# Can I host Vagrant/VirtualBox VMs on Azure Dedicated Host

Tags: virtualbox, azure, vagrant, cloud

I need to migrate a workload that comprises VMs into the Cloud, with Azure currently being my preferred option. The workload runs a test suite and must start several VMs with Vagrant and VirtualBox in its main script. I have established that the workload won't run on VMware because of VM-in-VM issues with VirtualBox. Hence I would like to order a dedicated physical (not: virtual) server  in the Cloud in order to circumnavigate any VM-in-VM issues.

Does such an offer exist in Azure? (I would assume so.) I have started investigating Azure Dedicated Hosts, but I'm currently a bit confused by parts of the documentation that say these use the same virtualization mechanism found elsewhere in Azure and they can run certain VM families as supported by Azure (Azure VMs).

My initial question (as I am learning about Azure) is this: Would an Azure Dedicated Host fulfill my requirements or is the are more suitable Azure service available? Is an Azure Dedicated Host a physical or still a virtual host? How can I be sure that I could my workload with Vagrant and VirtualBox VMs inside? (I don't care whether those VMs might show up in the Azure management UI, just that they can be employed, i.e. that the test suite can run.) Does one get root access to an Azure Dedicated Host (that was my initial assumption) or are Azure Dedicated Hosts mainly conceptual entities for controlling the placement of Azure VMs (that's what I suspect by now)?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Dedicated Hosts are still virtualized machines but with dedicated tenancy, ie the hosts are dedicated to you. They are, however still virtualized.

You would probably have to look at [Azure BareMetal Infrastructure](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/baremetal-infrastructure/concepts-baremetal-infrastructure-overview) for this.

Comment: Yes, Azure BareMetal Infrastructure is close, but I it seems retricted to either RHEL or SLES, whereas I would have chosen Debian first. Looks as if I'm out of luck with Azure and that specific choice.